# How to have One DNS and two different webhost?

Tags: google, web-hosting, subdomain, godaddy, blogger

I have one domain name i.e. example.com registered via godaddy.

- Now, I want to host my personal blog on blogger/blogspot with this
  url (i.e. on subdomain) "http://subdomain.example.com"
- And, I want to host my full website on different webhost (It is a
  free host which supports all the PHP features) but it does not allow 
  me to modify CNAME and A records of domain.
- Godaddy allows me to modify DNS Settings of my domain name
  including CNAME and A Records but only if it's name servers are used.

Now, Solve my Problem. I will be very much grateful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use Goddaddy nameservers
- Learn NS-management interface in order to add needed for 2 sites (**hosts**, not subdomains!) RR in zone definition
- Select names for your hosts (let they be www and blog in this example)
- Read blogspot docs about using your own hostname with service (it will be smth. like "you have to point your host to *somename-of-blogspot-domain*"). Do it, i.e add

`blog CNAME somename-of-blogspot-domain.`

to **your zone definition** (dot is a must)

- Order host on  independent hosting and remember IP of your future site
- Add to zone one more RR

  www A ip-ip-of-hosting
- Create www.domain site on hosting

Relax and have fun

Comment: What is RR here?

Comment: RR is abbreviation for **Resource Record** - formal name for string with data in zone-definition

Comment: Is it possible to apply this for *n* different web hosts?

Comment: @diegoaguilar - yes, why not? Just add more different `IN A` records